# Javascript, matching username and password with array values

Tags: javascript, validation

```
var usernames = ["smith",  "tron",      "ace",      "ladyj",    "anon"];
var passwords = ["qwerty", "EndOfLine", "year1942", "ladyj123", "PASSWORD"];
var x = prompt("Please enter the username");
var y = prompt("Please enter the password");

function validate(usernames, passwords) {
    for (var i=0; i <usernames.length; i++) {
        if ((x == usernames[i]) && (y == passwords[i])) {
            valid = true;
            break;  
        }
    }
    if (valid) {
        alert("Valid Credentials");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Credentials")
    }       
}
```

So I'm trying to create a loop that checks the username and pass with the entered prompt, so basically when prompted to enter a username and the user enters "smith" the correct password should be "qwerty" or if the user enters "tron" the correct password the user enters should be "EndOfLine" otherwise an alert saying "invalid Credentials" should pop up.

When I open the HTML file, I enter the user/pass but doesn't send any type of alert after entering the credentials.

Comment: maintaining passwords at client side is bad practice and user at any point can inspect and get all passwords from developer tools

Comment: Well what @Naga Sai A is true, but the reason your function is not working is due that `validate` is never called so before `if (valid)` just call `var valid = validate(x, y);` should do the trick

Comment: `validate` is a function, which you never call. The arrays are outside the `script` tag.

Comment: other issue from your code, you cannot declare variables in html and outside script tag

Comment: Bad Idea™ aside, a map `{ smith: "querty", tron: "EndOfLine", ... }` would simplify this logic greatly.

Comment: So I moved the arrays within the script tag and called the validate function (var valid = validate(x, y);) and I have the alerts popping up now, but no matter what I type it says its invalid

Answer (score 1):

You had a few things wrong:

1. The arrays for usernames and password were not in script tag.
2. Your function, `validate(usernames, passwords)` was never called
3. The variable `valid` has to be declared outside of the function

This should work.

```js
var usernames = ["smith",  "tron",      "ace",      "ladyj",    "anon"];
var passwords = ["qwerty", "EndOfLine", "year1942", "ladyj123", "PASSWORD"];

var x = prompt("Please enter the username");
var y = prompt("Please enter the password");

var valid = false;

validate(x, y);

function validate(username, password) {

    for (var i=0; i <usernames.length; i++) {
        if ((username == usernames[i]) && (password == passwords[i])) {
            valid = true;
            break;  
        }
    }
}

if(valid) {
  alert("valid credentials");
}
else {
  alert("invalid credentials");
}
```

Also, please don't save passwords on the client side

Answer (score 0):

Besides moving the arrays into the `<script>` tag and calling `validate()` somewhere, it may be a good practice to have it return the result, instead of setting a variable directly. Here the function returns `true` if there is a match in the loop, and if there were not any, it returns `false` at the end:

```js
var usernames = ["smith",  "tron",      "ace",      "ladyj",    "anon"];
var passwords = ["qwerty", "EndOfLine", "year1942", "ladyj123", "PASSWORD"];

function validate(username, password) {
    for (var i=0; i <usernames.length; i++) {
        if ((username === usernames[i]) && (password === passwords[i])) {
            return true; // match found
        }
    }
    return false; // match not found
}

var x = prompt("Please enter the username");
var y = prompt("Please enter the password");

var valid = validate(x, y);

if(valid) {
  alert("valid credentials");
}
else {
  alert("invalid credentials");
}
```

Also, in `JavaScript`, `===` should be used as basic comparison (for equality and `!==` for inequality). The shorter `==` and `!=` do various implicit conversations (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), which you may want to avoid at the beginning.